# How to capture Control+Tab on a NSView keyDown: event?

Tags: macos, cocoa

It looks like `keyDown:` isn't called when Control+Tab is pressed. I've a `NSView` to render custom widgets, so I need to capture Control+Tab for a custom behavior, but `NSApplication sendEvent:` [captures it to change the next key view](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH7-SW9). How can I intercept this to get Control+Tab in the `keyDown:` event?

Comment: This is kind of a long shot, I'll be following this question, but I have something you could maybe try?  I had a similar issue once, where I couldn't get the ESC key to register.  Turns out, I had to override a method in `NSResponder` called `-cancelOperation`.  That allowed me to recognize when the user had pressed ESC.  I wonder if there's a similar solution with TAB?  Go to `NSResponder.h` and search for `NSStandardKeyBindingMethods`.  I see maybe `-insertTab` could be what you're looking for?  Try implementing it, and throw in a log statement and see if it hits

Comment: Here's the comment in the header: > // This category contains a large number of methods intended for use as key binding commands.  NSResponder does not implement any of them.  NSTextView implements a certain subset of them (see the NSTextView.h header).  Your responder subclasses can implement any that make sense.  You can make up your own as well, but you should use these if the concepts map.  If your view is key and uses key binding and the user types a key sequence which is bound to a command which is not implemented in your class, it is OK, nothing will happen by default.

Comment: Did you try `performKeyEquivalent:`?

Comment: I've (temporarily) solved the issue [filtering the specific key event](https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite/blob/4acf12a47890e506999218e9e9aab77033e8d2ba/src/she/osx/event_queue.mm#L38) after `[NSApp nextEventMachingMask:]`. But it doesn't look as a generic solution and I didn't try Esc key yet or other key combinations that might be problematic. I'll be giving a try to those two alternatives and give you feedback soon.